# Separate two prometheus queries with a string

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Is it possible with grafana to separate two prometheus queries by a string?

[image]

Here, for example, I would like to add a "/" betwwen my values because I have "1/1" pods.

Comment: There is no such feature in the majority of standard panels. There is a text panel though, where you can put some custom text and augment it with values from dashboard variables. Although this leaves you without the possibility to colorize the value.

Comment: Thank you @anemyte for your answer. I will use a different approach for this. 
Regads :)